# Loop iteration continues before receiving further input

Tags: c++, class, object

I'm fairly new to using C++, so I'm having some issues -->

I'm sure I could do it another way simply using a function to check if the teacher wants to add another student. However, I believe this way should work. I ran into an error tho. The loop continues to iterate forever, printing "Would you like to add another student: y/n?". I thought it might be from leftover inputs being passed thru cin >> instructorChoice.

But if that was the case, shouldn't it stopped at the other cin(s)? Since it'll be meet them at one point, and again.

I also have another issue, I'm not sure how to print object attributes (I believe that's how you refer to them?), e.g. person.name(). Though I'm sure I'll figure that one out later, not much of a problem.
-->My print function in the header file.

I have a main file and a header file for my class. I'm not sure if that's the best way to go about it. I know it's a small program but I wanted to try getting into the habit of better file management while programming.

I'd appreciate any input. Thanks in advance.

```
/*
    Simple "Class" Project 1:

    This program allows a teacher to add a student to a list of student,
    once she/he is done. The program prints all the students in the list
    along with their grades. I'm testing the use of header files by defining
    my class and its methods there.

    - Me
*/

#include <vector>
#include  "student.h" //include files for student class
                      //includes <iostream>, <string>, namespace


int main() {
    //var declarations
    string studentName;
    int studentGrade;
    char instructorChoice;
    int i;

    //delcare student vector
    vector<Student> studentList;

    //take the initial input
    cout << "Would you like to add a new student: y/n?" << endl;
    cin >> instructorChoice;

    //run until no more students need to be addded
    while (instructorChoice == 'y') { 
        
        Student student; //create new student info

        //prompt for user info
        cout << "Student Name: ";
        cin >> studentName;

        cout << "Student Grade: ";
        cin >> studentGrade;

        student.SetName(studentName); //setName
        student.SetGrade(studentGrade); //setGrade
        studentList.push_back(student); //append to list of students

        //notify teacher!
        cout << student.GetName() << " has successfully been added!" << endl;

        //ask if they would like to add another student
        cout << "Would you like to add another student: y/n?" << endl;
        cin >> instructorChoice;

    }

    //print all 
    for (i = 0; i < studentList.size(); ++i) { //iterate through object vector
        studentList[i].PrintStudents();
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

```
/*
    Student Class Declaration
*/
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student {
    public:
        //set
        void SetName(string studentName);
        void SetGrade(char studentGrade);

        //get
        string GetName();
        int GetGrade();
        
        //print
        void PrintStudents();

    private:
        string name;
        char grade;

};


// public function definitions

//set
void Student::SetName(string studentName) { //Set new student name
    name = studentName;
}

void Student::SetGrade(char studentGrade) { //Set new student grade
    grade = studentGrade;
}


//get
string Student::GetName() { //return the student name
    return name;
}

int Student::GetGrade() { //return the student grade
    return grade;
}

//print
void Student::PrintStudents() { //Print student name and grade
    cout << "Student: " << name << " Grade: " << grade << endl;
}
```

I tried using cin.ignore();

and cout << flush;

Pretty much anything I can find to clear any leftover buffers/inputs. Didn't work.

Not sure what the issue exactly is.

Comment: Please don't tag languages you aren't using.  (Fixed)

Comment: What do you input? I suspect you try to input "John Doug" and the further `cin >> studentGrade` falls with `cin` in the fail state.

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  What input are you using, exactly?  Your code expects you to enter an integer for the grade.  Are you trying to enter a letter grade?  That would fail.

Comment: Your program is a big demo of a bad code. First of all you don't check if input was successful like `if (cin >> studentGrade)`.

Comment: questions asking for debugging help must include a [mcve] (ok) and input, output and expected output.

Comment: A problem with `cin >> ...` is that it makes VERY SPECIFIC ASSUMPTIONS about the format of data entered by the user, and things go to custard if the user doesn't comply.  A simple thing like entering `John Jones 47` when the code is `cin >> studentName; cin >> studentGrade` will mess things up (`studentName` gets the value `"John"`, the `J` in `Jones` messes up the reading of `studentGrade`).   This is one reason that `>>` is often not used in production code to read user input.... it is often *impossible* to ensure input is in the expected format, or even to recover sensibly when it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read your code.it's good for begin.

The reason for the infinite loop is that `grade` type in your class is `char` but in `main function` is `int`.

some wrong in clean code:

- write include in all file don't use nested.
- write function for `cout << "Would you like to add a new student: y/n?" << endl; cin >> instructorChoice;`. because is duplicate.

your print is not bad but you can write `string get_student_data()` and can use operator overloading(`operator<<`)

Comment: Yeah it was a data type error. I just had to change grade to char. Thanks guys! :D